# Pipeline data for Brazil

Tags: data, oil-gas, pipe-network, brazil

I am looking for oil and gas pipeline data for the area near Parnaiba, Brazil. I've spent hours search the web and I have yet to locate a source. Does anyone have any suggestions?

Comment: Perhaps a good question for http://opendata.stackexchange.com/

Comment: Pipeline information is normally heavily regulated in any country and often cannot be posted online. I would start with the ANP: National Petroleum Agency (Agência Nacional de Petróleo, Gás Natural e Biocombustíveis) since they have a division regulating on-shore pipelines.

Answer (score 3):

I suppose this depends your requirements regarding spatial accuracy. A very general guide to pipeline location could be:
http://www.theodora.com/pipelines

and in particular:
http://www.theodora.com/pipelines/argentina_bolivia_brazil_chile_ecuador_peru_uruguay_pipelines_map.html

If you are looking for something up-to-date and with a **better degree of accuracy** you will always have to **contact the country regulator/government** as pipelines are major infrastructure investments that therefore have a degree of security and control about them.

Contact ANP: National Petroleum Agency (Agência Nacional de Petróleo, Gás Natural e Biocombustíveis) as suggested by @blord-castillo - http://www.anp.gov.br/